# joomla module table of content category

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.4

I'm trying to find a module that would display a table of content of a given category and its sub-categories. Precisely:
Category 1
...Sub-cat 1.1
......article 1
...
......article n
...Sub-cat 1.2
......article 1
Category 2
...Sub-cat 2.1
......article 1

etc....

Using a "articles - category" module, I've got something that displays a list the article's titles followed by the name of their categories into parenthesis :-(
*...o article1 (category1)
....o article2 (category1)
*...o article1 (category2)
....o article2 (category2)
(where dots are to be replaced by spaces, * by bullets and o by empty bullets) etc...
It is close to the solution and the indentation (plain and empty bullets) proves that the information is collected.
I'm surely missing something but I don't know what...
Can somebody help me please ?
Cheers,
jc

Comment: Use the Articles-Categories Module.

Comment: Maybe not "articles - category" but "articles - categories". Shows sub-categories of a category. So you need to have a super category, which may be a good idea anyway. But: This does not list articles. For that you need "articles - category" after all. If you are not happy with the output, you might need a module template override (if you don't know what that is, google it, please.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@elin: Articles - Categories doesn't list articles as said Ralf and I want it, sorry. Articles - Category lists the articles following the hierarchy of the categories but the categories are shown after the titles of the articles between parentheses.
What I did is to create a Custom Module where I inserted 3 {loadmodule} of mod_articles_category for my 3 categories .
This did the job because I luckily have only 1 hierarchy level... otherwhile, yes Ralf, I would have been obliged to use an override :(
Many thanks for your mails.